# IDAPython doesn't recognize function

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, disassemblers, idapro-sdk

I'm developing a python script for IDA Pro that analyzes 32 bit PE files containing an anti-disassembly technique, the problem is that the function that contains the technique isn't being listed in the list of functions using `idautils.Functions()`.

To solve the problem I tried to add the function to the list with:

```
segm = idaapi.get_segm_by_name(".text")
    start = segm.start_ea
    end = segm.end_ea
    while start < end:
        start = idaapi.find_not_func(start, 1)
        ida_funcs.add_func(start)
```

When the `start` value is the address of the beginning of the function the `ida_funcs.add_func` method returns false, meaning that the address can't be added as a function, despite that in the GUI of IDA the function becomes listed.

This is the screenshot of the function containing the technique in the IDA GUI:
[image]

Do you know what can I do in order to have the script working? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using twice `idc.auto_wait()`, the first time at the start of the script and then between the snippet of code that I posted and the `idautils.Functions()`, now the function that I need to analyze gets listed.